# How to use String value of an enum within @RequestHeader(value=...)?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, enums, annotations, request-headers

I would like use the String 'key' value of an enum, as a 'value' parameter of @RequestHeader annotation.

```
@GetMapping(value = /fakeRoute)
@ResponseBody
private MyResponse handle(
        final @RequestHeader(value = "token") String userToken)
{
   ...
}
```

Instead of having **value = "token"** as seen above, I would like to use

```
@RequestHeader(value = MyCustomHeader.USER_TOKEN.getKey()) String userToken)
```

because I need to use the same header for many other requests.

But It does not allow me to use in that way. 
Do you have any suggestion?

---

MyCustomHeader enum class is sth like this (nothing special).

```
public enum MyCustomHeader {

    USER_TOKEN("token");

    @Getter
    private String key;

    MyCustomHeader(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774427/springs-requestparam-with-enum

Comment: You should not use dynamic variables and annotations values should be given at compile time.