# How to convert multiple values to enum in RequestParm?

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, http-request-parameters

I have this enum declaration below

```java
public enum FamilyType {
    FIRSTNAME("firstname"),
    LASTNAME("lastname");

    private final String type;

    FamilyType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static FamilyType fromString(String type) {
        for (FamilyType t : FamilyType.values()) {
            if (t.type.equals(type)) {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return converter(type);
    }

    @Deprecated
    private static FamilyType converter(String value) {
        if ("NICKNAME".equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return FIRSTNAME;
        }
        if ("SURENAME".equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return LASTNAME;
        }

        throw new InvalidFileNameException("my-enum", value);
    }
}
```

and I have a controller endpoint where the delete request holds the `FamilyType` as `Requestparam` like the following

```java
public String deleteFamilyType(@PathVariable String userId, @Valid @RequestParam FamilyType familyType) {
```

while sending from postman `familytype=firstname`, it works but if sending `familytype=nickname` then my converter returns

```
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'FamilyType';
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No enum constant FamilyType.NICKNAME
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.
```

Comment: Did you missed to add NICKNAME as enum value?

Comment: i dont have to, since there is converter to check it

Comment: the idea is to map it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [this tutorial section 3](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-enum-request-param), we can use custom converter to override the default conversion `Enum#valueOf`.

```java
public class StringToFamilyTypeConverter implements Converter<String, FamilyType> {
    @Override
    public FamilyType convert(String source) {
        if ("NICKNAME".equalsIgnoreCase(source)) {
            return FamilyType.FIRSTNAME;
        }
        if ("SURENAME".equalsIgnoreCase(source)) {
            return FamilyType.LASTNAME;
        }
        return FamilyType.valueOf(source.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

And then add the converter to MVC configuration

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToFamilyTypeConverter());
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type`

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full stacktrace?

Comment: it works with @requestBody so if the enum value is part of body but not in case of requestparam weired, its not even commes to convert method in class StringToFamilyTypeConverter

Comment: I think there is other configuration interfere, as the default behavior is case sensitive, but you can convert with lower case. I can't help much without the full source.

Comment: how to do that plz

Comment: So what addition step have you done? I am just interested.

Comment: there was ` webBinder.registerCustomEditor(FamilyType.class,
            new CaseInsensitiveConverter(FamilyType.class));`
in my initBinder so i removed it and worked, what do you think about it?

Comment: Thanks, everything make sense to me now, I suggest you also include the `initBinder` method in the post as this is one of the cause of the problem.