# How to make enum parameter lowercase in SpringBoot/Swagger?

Tags: spring-boot, enums, jackson, swagger

I have the following endpoint

```
@GetMapping(value = "/mypath/{mychoice}")
public ResponseClass generateEndpoint(
        @PathVariable("mychoice") FormatEnum format,
    )  {

...
```

and the following `enum` annotated with `Jackson`

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.KebabCaseStrategy.class)
public enum Format {
    AVRO,
    ORC,
    PARQUET,
    PROTOBUF
}
```

I hoped, `@JsonNaming` annotation will tell swagger to display cases in lowercase, but it doesn't

[image]

Adding `@JsonProperty` to each case also doesn't help.

---

It also doesn't accept lowercase URL with error

```
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'FormatEnum'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam FormatEnum] for value 'avro'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant FormatEnum.avro
```

Setting

```
 spring.jackson.mapper.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS = true
```

has no effect (and is `true` in code).

Looks like it just doesn't use Jackson to deserialize enum!

Comment: Please check if [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210546/how-to-convert-multiple-values-to-enum-in-requestparm/67214002#67214002) help.

Comment: Is there any solution for all enums?

Answer (score 1):

### Answering the part for serializing Enum case insensitive

The reason why setting `spring.jackson.mapper.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS=true` is not working can be found in [Konstantin Zyubin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157817/jackson-databind-enum-case-insensitive#answer-57793147).

And inspired from above answer, we can have a more generic approach to handle case insensitive enums in request parameter.

Converter class

```java
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class CaseInsensitiveEnumConverter<T extends Enum<T>> implements Converter<String, T> {
    private Class<T> enumClass;

    public CaseInsensitiveEnumConverter(Class<T> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T convert(String from) {
        return T.valueOf(enumClass, from.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Add in configuration

```java
import com.example.enums.EnumA;
import com.example.enums.EnumB;
import com.example.enums.FormatEnum;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        List<Class<? extends Enum>> enums = List.of(EnumA.class, EnumB.class, FormatEnum.class);
        enums.forEach(enumClass -> registry.addConverter(String.class, enumClass,
                      new CaseInsensitiveEnumConverter<>(enumClass)));
    }
}
```

Related: [Jackson databind enum case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157817/jackson-databind-enum-case-insensitive)

Comment: Yes, I did this way. I found example class existed in earlier versions of Spring (called `StringToEnumConverterFactory`). Also I have an explanation why isn't it work with Jackson: because enum value in URL IS NOT A JSON AT ALL (it is not quoted for example). It will not work in a body too, unless it is a valid JSON (for ex quoted or wrapped into other JSON).