# Spring springdoc-openapi : swagger-ui/index.html cannot be found status=404

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc

I've a spring boot application (2.5.6) with a dependency on springdoc-openapi.
However, launching swagger-ui (http://localhost:8080/v1/swagger-ui/index.html) doesn't work.
The debug logs are indicating that index.html is not present.
What could be the reason that index.html is not found ?

[image]

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

application.yaml

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    tagsSorter: alpha
    operations-sorter: alpha
    doc-expansion: none
    disable-swagger-default-url: true

logging:
  level:
    root: DEBUG

server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: fe-applic-app
    api-version: "v1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. The context-path was not set in application.yaml.

http://localhost:8080/**v1**/swagger-ui/index.html

After adding  **servlet : context-path**,  swagger-ui is rendered

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: "/${spring.application.api-version}"
```

Comment: awesome, great answer, fixed my problem. Based on this I added something similar in my application.properties `spring.application.api-version=v1
server.servlet.context-path=/${spring.application.api-version}`

Answer (score 4):

To share my experience because I have just spend more than 1 day to resolve a similar problem.

This can happen if the project contains a configuration class extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.

To be more precise :

- The `/v3/api-docs` route was working
- The `/swagger-ui/index.html` was throwing a 404 error

As I said, we had inside the project a configuration class extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` in order to automatically convert lowercase `String` inside the request to an uppercase `Enumeration` ([How to make enum parameter lowercase in SpringBoot/Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527893/how-to-make-enum-parameter-lowercase-in-springboot-swagger))

In this case, Spring creates first a bean extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` where the `addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry)` method does nothing (Empty method).

When this configuration class is not present, Spring creates a bean `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` but this class overrides the `addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry)` method to register all the `WebMvcConfigurer` beans to the `ResourceHandlerRegistry`.

So it adds the `SwaggerWebMvcConfigurer` that manages the route `swagger-ui/index.html`.

Comment: This was the cause of the problem for me, thank you! I solved it by refactoring the class that extended `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` to implement `WebMvcConfigurer` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try `swagger-ui.html` instead of `swagger-ui/index.html`. In 60% of the cases `swagger-ui.html` redirects to its real location.

http://localhost:8080/v1/swagger-ui.html
http://localhost:8080/v3/swagger-ui.html

Answer (score 2):

add this to your configs:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport
{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.14.3/");
    }
```

see [source](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/361#issuecomment-603976945)
and [static-resources](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using open API with spring 3. It will give 404 error. Hence use the   **springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui** dependency.
Later you can use the URL's

- http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
- http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Eg

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```