# 404 Not found for GET /v3/api-docs and /swagger-ui/index.html

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

On my local Spring Boot v2.17 application, I cannot access neither OpenAPI docs at /v3/api-docs nor /swagger-ui/index.html.

There are these dependencies in pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

My application.properties:

```
server.port=8069
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
```

I've tried http://localhost:8069/v3/api-docs and http://localhost:8069/swagger-ui/index.html, both giving 404 not found.

The project was created by another person, I'm wondering if something could be altering the mapping, that I understand is registered by the openapi packages?

Comment: Could it be that you need to use an older version of springdoc? https://springdoc.org/ Accroding to their website, springdoc-openapi v1.7.0 is the latest version that supports Spring Boot 2.x and 1.x.

Comment: Thanks @Sowik for the suggestion! I edited the dependencies accordingly, however still no luck.. There is still something else..

Comment: Perhaps something from here would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72317932/spring-springdoc-openapi-swagger-ui-index-html-cannot-be-found-status-404?rq=2 Could it be that whoever has created the project has changed the context-path? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path

Comment: Thanks @Sowik, but there's no context path. I went through the whole https://springdoc.org/v1/ and still no luck... I'm investigating further. It's odd because normally OpenAPI generation is pretty straightforward.