# In Spring Boot 2.5, how do I convert an enum with a String value to my @RequestParam?

Tags: spring-boot, enums, spring-restcontroller, http-request-parameters

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.  I have this enum

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1("Label 1"),
    VALUE2("Label 2"),
    VALUE3("Label 3");

    private String label;

    MyEnum(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

and this controller method that I want to accept the enum

```
...
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/my-endpoint")
    public String myEndpoint(@RequestParam MyEnum myEnum) {
        // Your code here
        return "Received enum value: " + myEnum + " with label: " + myEnum.getLabel();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I submit a request like "/my-endpoint?myEnum=label%201", I get the error, "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type".  What else do I need to do to allow conversion to happen successfully?

Comment: I would recommend passing in a string on the method and then getting the enum from it. you will probably need to create a custom converter and also make sure to check for the case sensitive as on your example `?myEnum=label%201` is != `VALUE1("Label 1")` label

Comment: And here is how you create a converter: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-enum-mapping

Comment: Your answer can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53266048/6118711

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring's @RequestParam with Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774427/springs-requestparam-with-enum)